# Kentico Bizform in a transformation

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

One of my companies clients uses the Kentico cms (a proprietary cms written in asp.net [kentico.com](http://kentico.com))

I would like to embed a bizform into the transformation of a custom table. The reason I need to do this is so that depending on a multiple choice option in the custom table, the transformation will display a different version of the bizform. If this is possible this will be the most efficient way of accomplishing what we need to get done.

I am pretty new to the Kentico CMS and it's proving to not be very devloper friendly, so ANY input or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A transformation in Kentico has the possibility to be a usercontrol.

If you use the Transformation type : ASCX, you can use any ASP.NET control you want.

Including the predefined Kentico usercontrols.

```
<cms:BizForm runat="server" ID="BizForm" FormName="YourBizFormCodeName" EnableViewState="false" AlternativeFormFullName="BizForm.YourBizFormCodeName.YourBizFormAlternativeFormName"/>
```

You can also give an AlternativeFormFullName to specify the alternative form you wish to use.